# Multiple instances of Sessionscoped Beans in the same session

Tags: java, dependency-injection, ejb, cdi

What happens if in the same session I instantiate more than one SessionScoped Bean or EJB (first time injected through the container and the second time created via "new")?
Will it throw an Error?
If not, which of them will be used during injection?
The same also for AppllicationScoped and RequestScoped?!

P.S. Classes do not have any annotation do give them an explicit name.

Comment: Why u want to instantiate more than one SessionScoped Bean ?

Comment: I do not want, but I see it in old code. And I want to know what happens and try to understand why the do it.

Comment: Spring was not tagged, but under Spring multiple beans of the same type could be resolved by using a unique name so each instance can be injected by name instead of relying just on the type.  There are other options for Spring such as using @Primary - see the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-metadata) for the details.  If Spring cannot resolve the bean dependencies then the app will not start.

Comment: Spring is not the case but good to know. In my case the classes have not explicit names. I will update my question. thnx

Comment: not sure what you mean by "instantiate more than one SessionScoped Bean".  a properly managed SessionScoped bean should not be instantiated but injected, which means the container is handling whether to either hand you one from the pool or create a new one if need be.  if you are properly letting the container manage the bean for you, you should be getting the same one back everytime, within the scope of the "session".  if you are instantiating it directly via "new", it's not really SessionScoped, but just an unmanaged pojo.

Comment: The first time it will be injected through the container and the second time it is created via "new".
But if what you said is correct, that the instance created with "new" is not a managed bean, then it is the answer to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have a truly managed bean, you let the CDI handle the lifecycle including the creation. There are exceptions, but let's not get into that now.

For your case, the object created via `new` will simply not be a managed bean and CDI will not know about it (unless it is a result of some producer method or such).
You should figure out why is it created at all instead of just injecting the existing one?

> The same also for AppllicationScoped and RequestScoped?!

For each injection point of a normal scoped bean, CDI will look into an underlying "bean store" and see if the bean you want was already created and stored there. If so, it just returns you that one (or, well, the proxy to it). If not, it will create a new one and store it there for future references.

So the short answer is, you won't have two instances of the same normal scoped bean created by CDI.

Comment: I think this is the right answer to this issue. I still cannot figure out for which reasone is this done this way. I thought is there any pattern, but as I understand there is none. Thnak you.